# Error: [$parse:ueoe] -- Getting error in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

Actually i'm using angularJS and getting error `Error: [$parse:ueoe]`. How can fix this error?

My Code:-

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Angular js tutorial';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

   
    <div ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>{{[message}}</h1>
    </div>
    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the bracket `[` that is causing the syntax error:

```
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bill P, it was my typing mistake,